# Kafka Streams getting into error state constantly and application is unable to start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have been working on kafka streams from quite some time. I am stuck in a problem and have't been able to solve it. I am expecting some help from this platform. 
So scenario is something like this. There are many customers and many employees working for those customers. There is a single topic storing all this data. I want to stream that topic
and want to build a meteralized store in a way that all the employee under same customer are grouped. I am using open source ListSerializer and ListDeserializer classes for this work.

So topic definition is something like this. c represent customer and e represents employee.

```
key   value
c1-e1  e1  
c1-e2  e2
c1-e3  e3
c2-e1  e4
c2-e2  e5
c3-e3  e6
```

I want this

```
c1 - [e1, e2, e3]
c2 - [e4, e5, e6]
```

I have used `ArrayListtSerializer` class which implements `Serializer<ArrayList<T>>`, here T is object which is `Employee`. `ArrayListDeserializer` implements `Deserializer<ArrayList<T>>`.

I have written below code to achieve this and code works fine. It read from topic and steam data in a store with customer-id as a key and list of employees as a value against that key.

```
KStream<String, Employee> source = builder.stream(topicName, consumed.with(Serdes.String(), getSerdeForObject(Employee));
Serde<Employee> employeeSerde = getSerdeForObject(Employee);
Serde<ArrayList<Employee>> employeeArrayListSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new ArrayListtSerializer<>(employeeSerde.serializer()), new ArrayListDeserializer<>(employeeSerde.deserializer()));

source.groupBy((k, v) -> v.getCustomer())
    .aggregate(() -> new ArrayList<>(), (key, value, aggregate) -> {
      aggregate.add(value);
      return aggregate;
    }, Materialized.<String, ArrayList<Employee>, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("NewStore")
        .withValueSerde(employeeArrayListSerde));
```

Now I am working to make list serializer and list deserializer classes a generic ones. Such that `ArrayListtSerializer` must be `ListtSerializer` which will implement `Serializer<List<T>>` instead of `Serializer<ArrayList<T>>`, and vice versa for list deserializer. I have transformed both `ArrayListtSerializer` and `ArrayListDeserializer` classes into these `ListtSerializer` and `ListDeserializer`and changed my code to this.

```
KStream<String, Employee> source = builder.stream(topicName, consumed.with(Serdes.String(), getSerdeForObject(Employee));
Serde<Employee> employeeSerde = getSerdeForObject(Employee);
Serde<List<Employee>> employeeListSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new ListtSerializer<>(employeeSerde.serializer()), new ListDeserializer<>(employeeSerde.deserializer()));

source.groupBy((k, v) -> v.getCustomer())
    .aggregate(() -> new ArrayList<>(), (key, value, aggregate) -> {
      aggregate.add(value);
      return aggregate;
    }, Materialized.<String, List<Employee>, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("NewStore")
        .withValueSerde(employeeListSerde));
```

After changing my code, streaming is constantly getting into error state and application fails to start. I am getting below below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to t
    he actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: Employee). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:302)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class Employee cannot be cast to class [B (Employee is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:157)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:101)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
        ... 25 more
```

I have spent enough time to understand the issue but I am still unable to get this. Can someone please help me to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% sure -- however, the stack trace shows `SinkNode.process(...)` indicating that the error come from a repartitioning step. -- I assume the you change the `StreamsConfig` default serdes between both examples -- After `groupBy()` the key serde will be taken from `StreamsConfig` (as you don't provide one explicitly) -- and default is `ByteArraySerializer`. Try to pass a `Produced` into `groupBy()` to set a key serde (or change `StreamsConfig`)

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer
>
> key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
>
> value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
>
> is not compatible to the actual key or value type
>
> key type: java.lang.String
>
> value type: Employee
>
> Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide
> correct Serdes via method parameters.

The error says is that you are trying to use `ByteArraySerializer` for serializing the `Employee` class.
The `ByteArraySerializer`, simply takes the `byte[]` and sends it (there is nothing to serialize here).

You therefore need to convert the `Employee` to a `byte[]` and send it or use an appropriate serializer for your `Employee` class, i.e. something that takes the `Employee` object and converts it into a `byte[]`.

You can either serialize/de-serialize your `Employee` object to JSON or Avro (to name a few).

For example, You can write a generic JSON serializer and de-serializer for all of your custom objects.

See [JsonSerializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonSerializer.html), [JsonDeserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonDeserializer.html) in Spring (even if you are not using Spring, you can take a look at the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonSerializer.java))

and then create a Serde out of the serializer and de-serializer.

Comment: Why my code above is working for arraylist and not list?

Comment: You said you have used `Serializer<ArrayList<T>>` which is specifically for `ArrayList` and not for all sub classes of `List`

Comment: Yes right. My Question is how is it working for ArrayList  and not for List if the problem is specific to Employee object serialization and deserialization.

Comment: For `List<Employee>` you are using Listserializer, but what about for just `Employee` class?

Comment: Actually getSerdeForObject(Employee) method is retrieving this:

 `Serdes.serdeFrom(new AvroSerializer<>(), new AvroDeserializer<>(Employee));` 
 `AvroSerializer` and `AvroDeserializer` are custom written classes for objects so I am already using avro.